# When to use was and had been in Passive Voice?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning difference if we use was and had been in passive voice in below context.
In my example I come to know that He was taken / killed by police/uncle. Then how I imagine what exactly happen in past which writer want to say.

1) After accident he was taken to hospital by Police.
2) After accident he had been taken to hospital by police.

And

1) He was murdered by his uncle.
2) He had been murdered by his uncle.

Comment: The use of "was" and "had been" are equivalent in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

was and had been are not equivalent

Was murdered: the murder occurred anytime in the past: He was dead for 5 hours.

Had been murdered: the murder occurred in the past prior to another event in the past: Before the police could arrive on the scene (event in the past), he had already been murdered (prior to the arrival of the police).

"After the accident he had been taken to the hospital by the police" does not make sense, because the accident was prior to the trip to the hospital.